# Is there a performance difference between DrawingSurface and DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid?

Tags: wpf, drawing, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In a Xaml/Direct3d application for Windows Phone 8, is there a performance difference between using DrawingSurface and DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

I managed to find useful information:

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662943(v=vs.105).aspx, under "The Direct3D with XAML project template"

"This template is recommended if you want to create a game that only uses the managed app as a thin wrapper around an essentially native game in order to take advantage of some of the features that are only available to managed apps, such as live tiles. This template uses the DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid control to display Direct3D graphics on the screen. Unlike the DrawingSurface control, this control must be placed at the root of the XAML tree and always covers the entire screen. Like the other template, the Direct3D code for rendering graphics is implemented in a separate Windows Phone Runtime component. **The frame rate of a Direct3D with XAML app is slightly better than a XAML with Direct3D app.**"

And from http://tiptoptool.com/tag/sdk/, under "DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid"

"DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid is a very special element that must always be the root element of a page and allows developers to render directly to the background from Direct3D using C++.  DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid, as its name implies, inherits from Grid so you can position child elements using Grid layout.  The child elements are automatically composed by the platform on top of the Direct3D rendered background.  **DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid allows developers to render directly, instead of requiring a copy (through a Direct3D swap chain) like DrawingSurface requires, which results in faster performance.**  DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid was introduced to support games or other apps that require ‘to the metal’ graphics performance, but also want to use existing XAML elements for UI and have access to some features not available in the native app model like Live Tiles or Notification"

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that the `DrawingSurface` should be used for drawing on only part of a screen e.g. in a control.

On the other hand, `DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid` is for fullscreen usage because the element acts as a grid i.e. you can add XAML elements *inside* it and arrange them as if you are using top-level grid layout.

As for the performance, I would say that for full screen usage, the latter form is more performant although I cannot state that as a fact.

Comment: The latter is 5-7% faster, but also more restrictive since is must be full screen and background only.

Comment: But it serves different purpose. So that restriction is not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

Another main difference is that `DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid` does not support Orientation. It always uses Portrait.